# Is a Caesar cipher on purely binary data unbreakable?

Tags: security, encryption

As far as I can see methods to break a simple Caesar Cipher rely on patterns in the source data, such as the frequency of vowels in the English language. I struggle to see how a simple cipher on binary data could be compromised, assuming the key length is equal to or greater than the length of the data to be encrypted (so the key bytes never repeat) and assuming the source binary data is scrambled so any underlying pattern is removed.

If I offer you a byte value of 152, there is no mathematical way to determine that original data was 52 and the key was 100 without the key.

Are my assumptions here correct and if not how could this simple encryption method be broken?

Comment: "assuming the source binary data is scrambled so any underlying pattern is removed." means you essentially already encrypted the information...

Comment: I see your point. In this case scrambling simply means rearranging the binary file, e.g. split into blocks of 128 bytes and arrange the position of the blocks based on the key.

Comment: you just described an addition onto the encryption algorithm, so its not a pure Caesar cipher. I dont know enough about code breaking to comment on how secure that combination is, but it is not JUST a caesar cipher

Comment: "If I offer you a byte value of 152, there is no mathematical way to determine that original data was 52 and the key was 100 without the key." - if key size == message size you essentially have a one time pad (don't reuse the key!). This works for letters too.

Comment: Better suited for [Crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> key length is equal to or greater than the length of the data to be encrypted

You're describing [one-time pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad). It is secure.

Caesar ciphers have keys that are much shorter than the message.